# Cross-compiling (unixlike to windows) with PyO3 and Maturin

Tags: python, rust, cross-compiling, pyo3

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with cross-compiling to windows with pyo3 and maturin.

The [pyo3 docs](https://pyo3.rs/master/building_and_distribution.html) say:

> Cross compiling PyO3 modules is relatively straightforward and
>   requires a few pieces of software:
>
> A toolchain for your target. The appropriate options in your Cargo
>   .config for the platform you're targeting and the toolchain you are
>   using. A Python interpreter that's already been compiled for your
>   target. The headers that match the above interpreter.

I've found [the interpreter from here](https://blog.filippo.io/easy-windows-and-linux-cross-compilers-for-macos/), but I don't understand how to get a windows python interpreter and libraries, or even what that means exactly.

I'm using [maturin](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin) to build the python wheels and it works well on OS X, but I don't know how to start cross-compiling for windows.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

The goal is a wheel per Python version / architecture / OS.

An easy way to achieve this is through external runners (e.g. gitub runners) and an action that compiles the package using `maturin` for each of the platforms.

[Here](https://github.com/mre/hyperjson/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml) is how [hyperjson](https://github.com/mre/hyperjson) does it.

Answer (score 1):

`pyo3` now has experimental Windows feature to bypass this process entirely using `python3-dll-a`. [Read more here](https://www.maturin.rs/distribution.html#cross-compile-to-windows).